# GoogleMaps - CodeIgniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando a seguinte library http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/ para realizar marcações no mapa, alguém que já usou a mesma poderia me dizer se é possível quando o usuário clicar no ponto vermelho aparecer uma caixa com algumas informações? Tentei procurar na documentação e não achei nada a respeito, ou se ainda há alguma outra forma de fazer isto nem que eu tenha que usar outra library.

O unico que eu achei seria o

```
$marker['title']
```

mas não é isso que eu gostaria pois seria mais de uma informação. 
Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No próprio link que você informou existe um video de como utilizar a biblioteca, neste video é mostrado exatamente o que você precisa.

A parte que você procura esta nos [7:04 minutos](https://youtu.be/Ldo6eP-EBZ8?t=7m4s)

```
$market['infowindow_content'] = 'SEU TEXT AQUI';
```